# using 2 scopes for api gmail using python

Tags: python, gmail

I want to use another scope or or 2 differents ones, to read and send emails. i add the 2 scopes but throws the error: ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.
I deleted the token.json file to run again and showed the error from above and it doesnt create another token.json file

I tried putting in a variable 2 scopes from the api gmail and i expect it to redirect me to a login page from gmail to authorize it

```
SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']

async def main2():

    creds = None
  
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPE[1])
   
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPE[1])
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds
```